# Ubuntu 14.04 no signal to television

Tags: 14.04, tv

I have two different laptops with Ubuntu14.04. One is a Dell Latitude D610 x32 the other is a HP G62 x64.
When I connect the Dell laptop to the tv,svga connection, the tv gets signal and shows my desktop up to when I logon, then the tv no longer gets signal from the laptop. Then when I shut down the tv once again gets signal. The TV always got signal with this laptop while it had Windows XP on it.

I have tried connecting the HP laptop with both svga and hdmi and always get signal. With the svga connected I get multiple desktops on the tv. With the hdmi connection I get nothing but the desktop wallpaper on the tv. None of the files/shortcuts I have on the desktop show up nor does any program that I may have open.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a driver for your computer? Check in auto updates. Also go to display settings and connect the tv. Does it show up? If it does click the tv on your computer and switch on "Mirror Display". Some things that worked for me is turning my TV on then off, and switching input.